# Why does the pseudocode of _mm_insert_ps calculate %8?

Tags: intrinsics, sse4

Within the intel intrinsics guide, the pseudocode for the operation of [_mm_insert_ps](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm_insert_ps&ig_expand=4081), the following is defined:

```
FOR j := 0 to 3
    i := j*32
    IF imm8[j%8]
        dst[i+31:i] := 0
    ELSE
        dst[i+31:i] := tmp2[i+31:i]
    FI
ENDFOR
```

. The access into `imm8` confuses me: `IF imm8[j%8]`. As `j` is within the range `0..3`, the modulo 8 part doesn't seem to do anything. Does this maybe signal a convertion that I am not aware of? Or is `%` not "modulo" in this case?

Comment: I think it's just a coding convention that they copy-paste everywhere. Somewhere between safe for modification and cargo-cult programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a pointless modulo.

Intel's documentation [for the corresponding asm instruction, `insertps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/insertps), doesn't use any `%` modulo operations in the pseudocode.  It uses `ZMASK ←imm8[3:0]` and then basically unrolls that part of the pseudocode where this uses a loop, with checks like

```
IF (ZMASK[2] = 1) THEN DEST[95:64]←00000000H
    ELSE DEST[95:64]←TMP2[95:64]
```

This is just showing how the low 4 bits of the immediate perform zero-masking on the 4 dword elements of the final result, after the insert of an element from another vector, or a scalar in memory.

(There's no intrinsic for insert directly from memory; you'd need an intrinsic for `movss` and then hope the compiler folds that load into a memory operand for `insertps`.  With a memory source, `imm8[7:6]` are ignored, just taking that scalar dword as the element to insert (that's the `ELSE COUNT_S←0` in the asm pseudocode), but then everything else works the same, including the zero-masking you're asking about.)